# ArcObjects C# : What are the valid inputs for IGxObjectProperties.GetProperty()?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, visual-studio

The function IGxObjectProperties.GetProperty() takes in a string, i.e. "ESRI_GxObject_Name".

So far, the ones I know are:

ESRI_GxObject_Name, ESRI_GxObject_FileSize, ESRI_GxObject_FileTime, ESRI_GxObject_FileMode, ESRI_GxObject_Type

What other strings are valid? There doesn't seem to be a complete list anywhere

Comment: For latest doc, don't count on Google. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#igxobjectproperties.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

You can get the valid properties like so:

```
IGxObject gxObj = <something>;
IGxObjectProperties props = gxObj as IGxObjectProperties;
for (int ii = 0; ii < props.PropertyCount; ii++)
{
    string name = "";
    object value = null;
    props.GetPropByIndex(ii, ref name, ref value);
}
```

---

[Valid strings will change based on what the GxObject represents.](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/cpp_vb6_vba_vcpp_doc/com/extendao/GxInterchangeObject.htm) I would assume other valid strings that exist by default will follow the same format as the strings your question.

> This optional interface is not relied on for any major functionality.
>   However, it does allow access to properties of a GxObject without
>   requiring a separate property or method to be declared to access each
>   separate piece of information. This allows new versions of your
>   GxObject to gain additional functionality without breaking binary
>   compatibility.

```
     IGxObjectProperties allows access to properties of a GxObject in a
     flexible manner.
```

> For the GetProperty method, you should support a minimum of two
>   properties, name and type, which are accessed via the strings
>   ESRI_GxObject_Name and ESRI_GxObject_Type.

Comment: I'm using a GxObject to represent a feature class in a file geodatabase. Is there a way for me to find out what the valid strings are?

Comment: I looked at a bit more documentation. It looks like you could use IGxObjectProperties.PropertyCount and IGxObjectProperties.GetProprByIndex to retrieve this information. [Documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGxObjectProperties_Interface/001400000159000000/)

Comment: @scMarth06 I have updated my answer